# state callback firing objects are not valid error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to use callback that will validate an input.

When I am trying to type in the textbox, I am having the error below.  Can someone help why I am having the error and how I can correct it.

Is callback not allowed?  What am I missing?

> Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {dispatchConfig, _targetInst, nativeEvent, type, target, currentTarget, eventPhase, bubbles, cancelable, timeStamp, defaultPrevented, isTrusted, isDefaultPrevented, isPropagationStopped, _dispatchListeners, _dispatchInstances}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
>       in div (created by HelloWorldWithPropertiesES5)
>       in HelloWorldWithPropertiesES5 (created by Parent2)
>       in Parent2 (created by App)
>       in div (created by App)
>       in App
>       at invariant (react-dom.development.js:55)

```
    import * as React from 'react';
interface IProps{
    userName?:string
}
const HelloWorldWithPropertiesES5= (props:IProps)=>{   
    return (
        <div>
            Hello {props.userName}
        </div> 
    )
    }

    export default HelloWorldWithPropertiesES5;
```

---

```
   import * as React from 'react'

interface IProps {
    userName : string;
    onChange : (event:any) => void;

  }

  export const NameEditComponent = (props : IProps) => 
  <>
  <h2>this shows event changes</h2>
    <label>Update name:</label>
    <input value={props.userName} 
           onChange={props.onChange}
    />

  </>

export default NameEditComponent;
```

---

```
 import * as React from 'react';
import HelloWorldWithPropertiesES5 from 'src/Lesson2-Properties/HelloES5';
import NameEditComponent from './MyChild';

interface IState {
  userName : string;
}

export class Parent2 extends React.Component<{},IState> {
  constructor(props:any) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {userName: 'defaultUserName'};
  }

  public setUsernameState = (newName:string) => {
          this.setState({userName:newName},()=>this.validateName());
    }



      public validateName () {
        if (this.state.userName.length === 0) {
         alert('error')

        }
      }

  public render() {
    return (
        <>
      <HelloWorldWithPropertiesES5 userName={this.state.userName} />
      <NameEditComponent userName={this.state.userName} onChange={this.setUsernameState} />
    </>
    );
  }
}

export default Parent2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The handler is returning the event, not the value directly.
I'm not a typescript expert so maybe my types in the signature are a bit off but it should be something like this:

```
public setUsernameState = (event: object) => {
  this.setState({ userName: event.target.value }, () => this.validateName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to validate your username before calling setState method
2. I think that input's onChange method is pushing event variable to your handler and event is not a string. So maybe in your `setUsernameState` you need to get a value of the input like `event.target.value`

Wrapping up... I think that your wrappper should look more like:

```
public setUsernameState = (event) => {
  const {newName} = event.target;
  if (!this.validateName(newName)) {
    customMethodToSetErrors();
  }
  this.setState({userName: newName});
}
```

EDIT:

sorry,, I did not know what setState's callback does... So your callback is fine and your problem should be only handler's argument type and the way that you are getting a new value :) So just try to get a new value from event object argument.